# Array adapter context

Tags: java, android, adapter

this is my code:

```
    public class EnterActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enter);

    Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);



    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             String[] answers = {
                    "das",
                    "das",
                    "dsa"
            };
            EditText eproduct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product);
            EditText efactory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.factory);
            GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

            String product = eproduct.getText().toString();
            String factory = efactory.getText().toString();

            FrenchList french = new FrenchList();
            int frenchResult = french.getCosher(product, factory);
            //error is here
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answers);

        }
    });
}}
```

the error is: "The constructor ArrayAdapter(new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined"

I did some searching on similar problems and I'm preety sure the problem is that i don't use the context properly, but to my understanding, as long as "this" appears in a class that extends activity I should be alright.
Why is this error showing? how can I fix it?

Comment: It's right there, method undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the `View.OnClickListener` class, which is an anonymous inner class in this example. You can use `EnterActivity.this`.